# Attempt to Use Bootstrap on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, devise

So, I am trying to use Bootstrap to format the shared links of the Devise gem.  My current iteration is the following:

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
<%= link_to "Log in" :class=>"btn btn-success btn-lg", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
<%= link_to "Sign up" :class=>"btn btn-info btn-lg", new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
<%= link_to "Forgot your password?" :class=>"btn btn-warning btn-lg", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

This is located, as a partial, under Devise->Shared.  There seems to be one unopened thread on here asking about this, but I couldn't find a solution and no attempt that I've made has resulted in a solution.  I keep getting syntax errors no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<%= link_to "Log in" :class=>"btn btn-success btn-lg",
    new_session_path(resource_name) %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to "Log in", new_session_path(resource_name), :class => "btn
btn-success btn-lg" %>
```

Same goes with other `link_to`.
See [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) docs.